# Sending email (using gmail & C#) Desktop or Web Based?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, newsletter

Friends,

I know there are lots of similar topics, but I'm creating this thread to take expert suggestions/guidance regarding my project for a non-profit NGO website. I'm a volunteer for rotary International and `They need a utility which can be used to send their newsletter`.

- I'm not aware of the kind of email database they have, let's assume
  **.xls file** with three columns (to, cc, bcc), maybe 1000s of data,
- **No database is available in their hosting plans**, and I can't make
  them spend now.
- Most probably a **msword (.doc) file** would be available with some heavy
  images as newsletter.
- They have **google apps ID**

**So what I'm seeking is: A way which is Right, shortest, quick, and easy to understand.**

Lot of code is available on the internet but the right way to do things comes only with experience. So plz suggest me what do u say about this?

Standalone/Desktop, or web based? A WinForm application, or ASP.NET?

*Desktop application* may hang/crash due to 1000s of mail requests on google. *Web application* may force them to share their email database on ftp and then I will need to create another way to subscribe & unsubscribe online.

Plz help me start...

Comment: we can access gmail and send mails but they will treat as spam if we send more mails

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd use (and do use) an integrated mailing system such as [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/)

Why re-invent the wheel right? Services like this allow for uploading data from many types of storage, they manage your suscriptions and provide an easy method for users to unsubscribe.

Comment: sure I was thinking about that, but there's nobody to take care of it after developement. I've checked their hosting account, and to my surprise they've not got it in hosting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Nobody to take care of what? What's their hosting account got to do with it?

Comment: I mean I'm not aware of how & who will be sending future newsletters from their side, so I was not sure if this system will be easy to undertand for them. Moreover I'm not able to find milchimp link in their google apps domain. silly me...

Comment: Their Google apps stuff is irrelevant here as I see it. MailChip will likely be easier to use for an inexperienced user than something custom built, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

You've suggested in your comment on Jamie's answer that you're worried about there being "nobody to take care of it after development" - but who's going to take care of whatever code you write?  At least a system like MailChimp has documentation and is understood by a small but accessible group of people: code you write will only be understood by you, and won't be maintainable or extensible.

As with any project, there is no "right."  There are simply tradeoffs.  You've talked about automation of thousands of emails, subscribing and unsubscribing, and basing the email on a Word document.  That's a lot of functionality to ask for help with on a simple Q&A site.

You say "Desktop application may hang/crash" - but that's equally true of a web application, you just won't *see* the hang.  The trick would be to code your application in a way that *doesn't* hang.

Comment: right @dan Puzey... maybe I'm worring too much in the starting itself..... clam down... calm down... :P But the main question is.... I don't think I can ever convince them about Paying more for an application which can be free of cost. who will pay for it my friend...

Comment: "Clam down calm down?"  I am answering your question, offering you free advice; I am perfectly calm.  Unfortunately StackOverflow isn't a site that's here to help you write a system from scratch; it's here to answer specific technical questions.  Your "main question" doesn't belong: if your customers aren't willing to pay for an application and want something hand-developed for free, that's it's not a problem you'll find an answer to here.

Comment: I thought u scolded me, its okie now. :) U maybe right that this place in not a correct place to ask such a question, but where else I can get advice from experts who spend their real time with codes & functions. I felt this is the best place to ask for suggestions to start my work. Later I will obviously be asking specific Qs.